# Возможно ли через 1 ajax передать  в два разных дива

Tags: jquery, php

есть  стандартный ajax

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: path_shell,
                cache:false,
                data:{flag_iq:2},
                success: function(data){
                          $('#main').html(data) ;   
                        }
```

Можно ли как то сделать выборку и вывести часть в #main а часть в другое место? и если возможно то как?

Comment: ``data = {div1: ..., div2: ...}`` ?

Comment: Ответ сервера хранится в переменной data в виде строки, соответственно можете с ним делать внутри функции ответа все, что можно со строкой. Видимо у Вас еще недостаточно знаний JavaScript и JQuery.